# knock out observable for telerik radcaptcha

Tags: validation, knockout.js, telerik

I am trying out with knockout validation. 
I understand that i am able to use observable for inputs, i.e

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="TxtName" runat="server" data-bind="value:Name"></asp:TextBox>


 var self = this;     
  self.Name = ko.observable().extend({ required: { message: "Please enter your name." } });
```

but what if i am going to do a validation for a telerik radcaptcha

```
    <telerik:RadCaptcha ID="RadCaptcha" runat="server"></telerik:RadCaptcha>
```

Am i able to do an observable to check if the radcaptcha is valid and display a message if its not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons it is not possible to perform a client-side check on the Telerik `RadCaptcha` control. Think about it, if client side validation was enabled it would be possible to create a program to bombard the input with responses until the correct one was found.

See Telerik Forum Posts:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/captcha/rad-captcha-client-side-validation.aspx

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/captcha/client-side-support-needed-for-radcaptcha.aspx